# Pandas dataframe group: sum one column and count number of values greater than 0 in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I followed the answer from "*Pandas dataframe group: sum one column, take the first element from others*", and it worked like a charm. However, in addition to that, I also have a column, which I want to count the number of times a value is larger than 0 (For each row).

My data looks like this

| Date | ID | Street | Supply | Demand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | 1 | Test1 | 100 | 70 |
| 1/2 | 1 | Test1 | 150 | 90 |
| 1/1 | 2 | Test2 | 160 | 80 |

And my desired output is this:

| Unique ID | First Street | Total Supply | count of times total supply is > 0 | Days since last supply |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | 250 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | Test2 | 160 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | Test3 | 300 | 4 | 1 |

Currently, I have used this code

```
# Import modules

import pandas as pd

# Import and merge data
TGTG_data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv('2019.csv'),pd.read_csv('2020.csv'),pd.read_csv('2021.csv')], ignore_index=True)

# Create dictionary

d = {'Supply':'sum','Meels save':'sum', 'Street':'first', 'Time':['min','max']}

# Group by StoreID and aggregate by dictionary
MetaData = TGTG_data.groupby('StoreID', as_index=False).agg(d)

# Rename columns
MetaData = MetaData.rename(columns={'first':'', 'sum':''})
MetaData.columns = ['{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format(x).strip('_') for x in MetaData.columns]
```

Comment: You can format your code with stackoverflow, f.i. by marking your code and pressing Ctrl+K on your keyboard. Furthermore we can't access data which is stored **locally** on your hard drive. Could you please upload some sample data?

Comment: In question misisng how looks expected output from sample data, also what means `Days since last supply` ? the best is change data sample for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and the mistakes I made is because I'm new to this site. 

How do I upload sample data?

However - All three CSV files looks identical to the table I posted in my question. There is 1 datapoint each day for each ID - I have edited the example of my date to better represent how it really looks.